# Assign default value to variable SQL Express

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm attempting to create a variable in SQL Express, the catch is I want the default value to come from a query and I can't quite figure it out.  Here's what I want to do:

```
DECLARE @myVar int = select max(MYCOLUMN) from MYTABLE;

select (someColumn / @myVar) as newCol
from MYTABLE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @myVar int = 0;
select @myVar =  max(MYCOLUMN) 
from MYTABLE;

select (someColumn / @myVar) as newCol
from MYTABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

All you are really missing are parenthesis around the value you are trying to set up as the default.

```
DECLARE @myVar INT = (SELECT MAX(MYCOLUMN) FROM MYTABLE)

SELECT (someColumn / @myVar) AS newCol
FROM MYTABLE
```